# SQL query to get data from last 40 months

Tags: sql

I have written a query to display the number of sales that were made in the last 40 months for below table

```
TABLE NAME: Sale
SALEID  SID  SLDATE
1001    1    01-JAN-14
1002    5    02-JAN-14
1003    4    01-FEB-14
1004    1    01-MAR-14
1005    2    01-FEB-14
1006    1    01-JUN-15

SELECT COUNT(SLDATE)  AS SALE_COUNT FROM Sale WHERE SLDATE <= 
ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE, -40);   /*MY QUERY LOGIC*/

EXPECTED RESULT:
 SALE_COUNT
 ----------
    0
```

What I got is:

> "ERROR: YOUR QUERY MATCHES OUTPUT EXPECTED RESULT, BUT THERE ARE LOGICAL ERRORS."

Comment: What are the errors?  Are you storing your dates as strings?

Comment: mysql got add_months()?

Comment: Please don't put your title in all caps. That's considered shouting, and that's frowned upon. (-1/edited)

Comment: I don't think any database will return that message. In which context are you running this? Is this some kind of tutorial site?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as SALE_COUNT from sale where sldate <= add_
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(SLDATE) SALE_COUNT FROM SALE
WHERE SLDATE = ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE,-40);
```

Try this as well. It will

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
select COUNT(SLDATE) from Sale where SLDATE > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 40 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(SALEID) SALE_COUNT FROM SALE WHERE SLDATE< = ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE, -40)
```

as you have to count SALES so we`ll count SALEID instead of SALE DATE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(SaleId) AS "SALE_COUNT" FROM Sale WHERE Sldate < = ADD_MONTHS('01-JUN-15', -40);
```

In `Sldate` Column, we should take the maximum date. `SYSDATE` will be inappropriate here because it depends when you are solving.  As we cannot use `MAX()` function in `WHERE` Clause we manually choose the max date from the `Sldate` column and add -40 for months deduction.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) SALE_COUNT FROM SALE WHERE SLDATE <= ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE, -40);`

Above query is right.

[image: Check out the image]

Answer (score 0):

select COUNT(Saleid) as SALE_COUNT from Sale where Sldate between SYSDATE-40 AND SYSDATE;

I think this query may work. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Last 40 months means from the current date, that's why you are getting logic error. You should try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(SLDATE) AS SALE_COUNT FROM Sale WHERE SLDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -40);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) sale_count from sale where add_months(sldate,40)>=sysdate
```

Comment: Would be helpful to add some context around your answer as opposed to only leaving a code snippet as an answer.